# Can I perform a 256 bit AES encoding/decoding in windowsphone 8.1

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-phone-8.1

I need AES enryption/Decryption foe an app in wp8.1. I used AES managed class under system.securuty.cryptography namespace for the app in Wp8 . I came acreoss some references like replace the name space with Windows.security.cryptography. I tried and stil couldnt find any thing. Can Somebody help me with a sample?

I tried the following code and it says AES managed cannot be found

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
//using Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core;
using Cimbalino.Toolkit.Extensions;
//using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace telyads.Utils
{
    class TACryptoModule
    {

        public string GenerateAESKey()
        {


            //var g = (Guid.NewGuid()).ToString();
            //var key = g.GetBytes().ComputeMD5Hash().ToBase64String();

            AesManaged KeyGen = new AesManaged();
            return (KeyGen.Key).ComputeMD5Hash().ToBase64String();


        }

        public string AESEncrypt(string data, string key)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public string AESDecrypt(string data, string key)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://janhannemann.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/simple-encryption-for-windows-winrt-and-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio's Object Browser scoped to "My Solution" to find classes that exist for your solution type. Searching on AES finds several AES variants available in [Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/br212102.aspx). You can acquire a provider by passing a SymmetricKeyAlgorithm.Name to the SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider and then using it with the CryptographicEngine class.

```
string strAlgName = SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcb;
SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlg = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAlgName);
```

There is a fuller code snippet in the [SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.openalgorithm.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) documentation and in the [Encrypting data and working with certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464985.aspx) section on MSDN.

You can find Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core.HashAlgorithmNames.Md5 in the same way and a snippet showing how to [hash objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh802428.aspx)

[image: Object Browser searching for AES classes]

Comment: How to do AES encryption using any of these? I didn't find a proper documentation anywhere.